# Tableau year-to-year change in grand total

Tags: tableau

New to Tableau and having some problems with a calculation I thought would be easy.

I have data with one value per month running across a few years. I would simply like to display a table with the change from month to month in percent and the change from start of year to end of year in percent as a grand total.

The input data looks like this:
[image: Example of raw data]

And I would like to create a table like this:
[image]

The month to month change is easy enough using a table calculation with "Percent difference from" and "across then down", but the yearly change has me frustrated by now as I keep getting weird values. I tried to create a calculated field using offsets in the table, but of course it doesn't work when applied in grand total using the 'Size()' trick.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0):

**Across_then_down** calculation works fine with row grand totals.
[image]

What do you mean by 20% in the first row Grand Total in the 'output' table? 20% relative to what?